# How to specify Log4j ConversionPattern for Logstash on sender side?

Tags: jboss, log4j, logstash

I have this on sender side (log4j.properties file for jboss):

```
log4j.appender.LOGSTASH=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.LOGSTASH.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGSTASH.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %t %d{ISO8601} %l - %m%n
log4j.appender.LOGSTASH.RemoteHost=my.server.com
log4j.appender.LOGSTASH.ReconnectionDelay=60000
log4j.appender.LOGSTASH.Threshold=DEBUG
```

But on receiving side I always receive some default message, ConversionPattern doesnt work, even I remove everything and put just a text there. I have four jboss instances, so it is critical to me to define on every sender side some specific text, e.g. `log4j.appender.LOGSTASH.layout.ConversionPattern=server1 %-5p %t %d{ISO8601} %l - %m%n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SocketAppender doesn't allow a PatternLayout see: **[How to use Pattern layout with SocketAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270504/how-to-use-pattern-layout-with-socketappender)**

You'll probably need to use the `SyslogAppender` or the `TelnetAppender` to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that I can deserialize logs on receiver side, but it is quite time consuming :( but seems I dont have any other option.
I will use shipper.conf for Logstash (on receiving side) for these purposes.

Comment: You may run into issues with the SyslogAppender as most syslog servers will truncate messages longer than 1024 chars by default. That would include stack-traces that you'd obviously want to capture.

Comment: You can use the SyslogAppender to log directly to logstash's syslog input without worrying about that I think (I've never done that, but it should work)

Answer (score 0):

Or write your own appender, It's actually pretty easy. Just extend org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.

Here is my attempt at a ZeroMQ ([http://zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual](http://zeromq.org/intro%3aread-the-manual)) appender and JSON (needs minimal processing) layout that I use for Logstash.

https://github.com/stuart-warren/logit

Produces output similar to:

```
{"message":"Hello World!","test":"other","@timestamp":"2013-10-06T21:22:09.868Z","level":"DEBUG","mdc":{"field_name_here":"detail goes here"},"thread":"main","logger":"com.stuartwarren.test_logit.log4j1.LogIt","@version":"1"}
```

Note: far from perfect, but not a bad first shot for an infrastructure guy.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot use your proposal, because it is enterprise environment.

Comment: Which proposal exactly? Writing your own appender/layout or using the hacky one I linked to? Can you edit your question to state what your limits are, then we can give a more suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Logstash log4j plugin https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.1/lib/logstash/inputs/log4j.rb that I assume you are using, appears to extract the hostname from the sending server to the `host` field. Is that not sufficient?

It should also extract objects from the `MDC` and `NDC` log4j structures, if it is an internal application your developers could set something in there, or allow you to set a value in the startup params.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html

With my `com.stuartwarren.logit.log4j1.Layout` code you can just add your custom fields in the config file, but the `SocketAppender` doesn't appear to give you that ability as you can't set/change the layout.