# logstash log events contain stacktrace information when configured with properties file, but not when configured in java code.

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, log4j, logstash

I am relatively new to using Log4j and logstash. I am using Log4j with a socket appender to push log events to logstash-1.4.2 and then on to Elasticsearch-1.1.1 for storage.

I have tried generating the logging properties through an external properties file (log4j.properties) and through the java code. Both approaches seem to work with one exception: The log events created with the properties specified in the code do not generate the stack trace information that those generated with an external properties file generate.

I have looked at the logstash documentation as well as the Apache Log4J docs to see if there is any reason why this may be happening but have found nothing.
It looks like using an external properties file is the preferred method for this, but I would like to understand what is happening here.

When I utilize a properties file and use PropertyConfigurator I get all of the stacktrace information:

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server 

###SocketAppender###
log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=9500
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

**LoggingTestClass.java**

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingTestClass.class.getName());
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); 

logger.debug("debug message");
logger.error("error message");
```

-this generates the log event below with all of the following class/file/line/method information in the event.

```
"message": "debug message",
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2014-08-08T16:08:10.423Z",
"type": "testLogs",
"host": "127.0.0.1:59979",
"path": "log4J.LoggingTestClass",
"priority": "DEBUG",
"logger_name": "log4J.LoggingTestClass",
"thread": "main",
"class": "log4J.LoggingTestClass",
"file": "LoggingTestClass.java:20",
"method": "init"
```

However, when I create a SocketAppender object and specify the properties in the java class I still get the logging events, but they are missing their stacktrace information:

**LoggingTestClass.java**

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();

SocketAppender sa = new SocketAppender("localhost", 9500);
sa.setPort(9500);
sa.setRemoteHost("localhost");
sa.setReconnectionDelay(10000);
sa.activateOptions();

logger.addAppender(sa);

logger.debug("debug message");
logger.error("error message");
```

This generates the same information in the logged event with the exception that the class/file/line/method information of the resulting log events is missing:

```
"message": "debug message",
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2014-08-08T14:27:27.522Z",
"type": "testLogs",
"host": "127.0.0.1:62135",
"path": "log4J.LoggingTestClass",
"priority": "DEBUG",
"logger_name": "log4J.LoggingTestClass",
"thread": "main",
"class": "?",
"file": "?:?",
"method": "?"
```

my logstash configuration:

**ESLogConfig.txt**

```
input {
   log4j {
      mode => "server"
      port => 9500
      type => Log4j
   }
}
output {
   stdout { }
   elasticsearch {
      cluster => "aaronCluster"
   }
}
```

Is there, perhaps, something I am neglecting to do while setting up the SocketAppender object?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `socketAppender.setLocationInformation(true)` -- accordindg to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html#setLocationInfo%28boolean%29 that's what you want.  I'm not sure why configuring with a `PropertyConfigurator` would set this, but the docs say it's `false` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried adding a PatternLayout to the socketappender but am seeing the same result in the logs.                                             String pattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n";
sa.setLayout(new PatternLayout(pattern));  logger.addAppender(sa);

Comment: Also it looks like SocketAppenders don't actually use layouts as they serialize all of the data. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270504/how-to-use-pattern-layout-with-socketappender). The config file I was using also contained no more than I included in my post so there was not a layout specified. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry for the incorrect original answer.  Edited it to be what I believe is the correct answer.

Comment: @OwlBear If you want to use `PatternLayout` with `SocketAppender`, you may want to consider upgrading to Log4j v2, which allows it: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender (use `layout=PatternLayout`, because the default layout is `SerializedLayout`)