# SocketAppender and PatternLayout

Tags: logging, log4j, appender

I have a logger that send log to a log server storage. This work fine but the **patternlayout** isn't used. With or without that doesn't change anything. I believe remember to read somewhere that **socketappender** use is own pattern and not others.

```
<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender"> 
        <param name="Port" value="5000"/>
        <param name="RemoteHost" value="192.168.81.131"/> 
        <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="5000"/>
        <param name="LocationInfo" value="true" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
      </layout>
</appender>
```

But on this [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) (and a few other) thay use this. Example from this doc :

```
<appender name="A1" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">
    <param name="RemoteHost" value="localhost"/>
    <param name="Port" value="5000"/>
    <param name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    </appender>
```

So is it impossible to use personnal pattern with **socketappender** or is it my fault?

If it's impossible is there an alternative appender for tcp logging with custom pattern?

Comment: Already found [this subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270504/how-to-use-pattern-layout-with-socketappender) but don't help me to know alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that **SocketAppender** don't use a layout.

> SocketAppenders do not use a layout. They ship a serialized LoggingEvent object to the server side.

[See documentation here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html)

---

So I use a **SyslogAppender** to replace. It's not perfect because of unused possibilies (like facility and priority) but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround,

- For Log4j 1.x
- Copy SocketAppender code to your local project
- Change, "requiresLayout" method as

  ```
      public boolean requiresLayout() {
              return true;
      }
  ```
- Change append method as ;

  ```
   public void append(LoggingEvent event) {

      ///......

      event.getThrowableStrRep();

      if (this.layout == null) {
          errorHandler.error("No layout for appender " + name,
                  null, ErrorCode.MISSING_LAYOUT);
          return;
      }

      String message = this.layout.format(event);

      oos.writeObject(message);
      ///...... 
   }
  ```
- Set this class as your appender.
- Now on, you can set any layout to this appender.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that @myuce posted is working, but you also need to replace *ObjectOutputStream* (OOS) within "standard" *OutputStream* (OS).

You can check inside OOS - it's prepending output with some additional stuff for "the receiver".

`??t?{"@timestamp":"2018-03-27T14...`

So... I've just replaced (it's scala in my case):

`oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new Socket(address, port).getOutputStream());` and
`oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());`

within:
`stream = new Socket(address, port).getOutputStream` and `stream = socket.getOutputStream` (and variable name [of course every occurrence;] for clarity).